# can't unbind a element with jquery

Tags: jquery, bind

I am working on a project where this jquery event was created:

```
$('input.checkout-continue:not(.checkout-processed)', context).addClass('checkout-processed').click(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.clone().insertAfter(this).attr('disabled', true).next().removeClass('element-invisible');
      $this.hide();
    });
```

This prevents a user from clicking the submit button twice.
I wrote a submit event and I need to temporarily unbind that event and put it back on when I am done. (I need to do this because otherwise, after I click submit, the button freezes and doesnt respond.) I tried starting with this:

```
$('input.checkout-continue:not(.checkout-processed)').unbind("click");
        $('#commerce-checkout-form-checkout').submit(function() {
          if($('#donation-amount-selection-form .form-item-donation-amount').val() == "" &&
             $('#donation-amount-selection-form .form-item-donation-custom-amount').val() == "") {
            var message = "Please enter a donation amount"
            $('#donation-amount-selection-form').prepend(message);
            event.preventDefault();
          }
```

but its not unbinding, the submit button remains frozen.

Answer (score 1):

The event is not unbinding because the selector: `'input.checkout-continue:not(.checkout-processed)` is written to only select elements without the `.checkout-processed` CSS class. That class is being added in the beginning:

```js
$('input.checkout-continue:not(.checkout-processed)', context).addClass('checkout-processed');
```

In order to unbind clicks to `input.checkout-continue` it is best to cache the jQuery object so that you can reference it later without re-querying the DOM.

```js
// Caches the selector since we'll use it to bind and unbind.
var $input = $('input.checkout-continue:not(.checkout-processed)');

var onClick = function () {

  // Caches the clicked element.
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.attr('disabled', true);

  // After some time, re-enable the button but unbind the click event.
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $this.attr('disabled', false);
    $input.unbind('click', onClick);
  }, 3000);

};

$input.bind('click', onClick);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/IwudIBO/2/edit)

In this example we only need to set the `disabled` attribute to on/off to toggle the input's state (there is no need to clone and hide it).

Comment: I don't understand your code. First of all, was it un-intentional that you added in the not(.checkout-processed) in the actual code when you said that's the wrong selector? Second, where is the jquery submit event anywhere? I only see the onClick variable. I therefore don't understand what $this is refering to.

Comment: I just tried $('input.checkout-continue').unbind("click"); to see if it would unbind the event, but it doesn't